# Joining polygon layer attributes to line segments in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, line, spatial-join, overlapping-features

I've got a hexagon layer with data that I want to have joined to the available road network for the area so that the road segments have the attributes from the hexagon layer.

Each segment of the road layer is comprised by the intersection of two roads, there are a total of 304 features. The features that go through multiple polygons should account for the average value of these polygons. Say that `H_1 = 0.4` and `H_4 = 0.2` (whereas H -> hex polygon bin) thus, `(H_1+H_4)/n` (where n the number of polygons that intersect the line layer).

How can I do that?

Comment: Is your road layer one segment per feature? What about features that go through multiple hexagons? Or do you also want the lines cut at hexagon border points?

Comment: Usually I'd say `intersect`, but that depends on your answer to the questions above.

Comment: Thanks for your questions:
(i) Each segment of the road layer is comprised by the intersection of two roads, there are a total of 304 features.
(ii) The features that go through multiple polygons should account for the average value of these polygons. Say that H_1 = 0.4 and H_4 = 0.2 (whereas H -> hex polygon bin) thus, (H_1+H_4)/n (where n the number of polygons that intersect the line layer. 

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add your solution to the question body. Instead, use "Answer Your Question" button below.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**:

Intersection with the road layer in regards to the hexagon layer served the purpose well without complicating things too much.

Conversion of comparison of the two layers was conducted as follows (added for replicability purposes):

```
Vector -> Geoprocessing Tools -> Intersection
```

```
Input layer: road layer
```

```
Overlay: Hexagon bins
```

```
Input fields: ID
```

Overlay fields to keep: variable (I wanted to assess per road network just
a single variable)

Comment: Adding a screenshot, either to the question or the answer, helps to understand what you are doing. The additional information from your comment should be included in the original question, that helps to keep a clear view.